# Spring Boot data.sql initialization of H2 database has issue with backslash followed by single quote

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, h2

In some Spring Boot app I initialize my in-memory H2 DB with some inserts (in the `data.sql` file). One of the tables in the DB is filled with rows where each row has a string column, and every string in this column ends with a backslash e.g. `'\1\'`.

The backslashes are not treated as an escape character hence inserting `'\1'` inserts this string literally (no need for double backslashes). However, the backslash before the single quote seems to escape that single quote, as inserting `'\1\'` causes a syntax-related exception. If I insert `'\1\\'` then that string is put in the DB literally (with the two backslashes at the end).

[In the H2 docs relating to the string data type](https://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html?highlight=escape&search=escape#string) I can't find any information on this. I tried prefixing my strings with `U&` to use unicode chars but this throws an error as well. The only fix I found so far is to add a space after the last backslash and do an update after insertion (using the `TRIM` function) to remove said spaces.

Is this behaviour explained anywhere, or is there a better way to circumvent the issue?

---

**Minimal example :**

Setup : Spring Boot test suite with `schema.sql` and `data.sql` given below :

`schema.sql`

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST;

CREATE TABLE TEST.ONE (
    IDENTIFIER BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(500)
);

CREATE TABLE TEST.TWO (
    IDENTIFIER BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(500)
);
```

`data.sql`

```
INSERT INTO TEST.ONE(IDENTIFIER,NAME) VALUES
    (1,'\1\3\');

INSERT INTO TEST.TWO(IDENTIFIER,NAME) VALUES
    (1,'test;test');
```

I have the following in my `application.properties` :

```
server.port=8083
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data-test.sql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source=script
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source=drop-tables.sql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=TEST
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.application.admin.jmx-name=org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication${random.int(1000000)}
```

- Expected behaviour : script runs fine
- Actual behaviour : script fails
  to run, because the semicolon in the second inserted tuple is
  interpreted as the end of the insert statement. If you add a space
  after the backslash in the first inserted tuple, the script does run.
  If you reverse the order of the inserts, it also runs.

H2 driver version 1.4.200

Comment: You're using `PreparedStatement` with parameters I hope? Since you've posted no code, we can only guess, which wastes time

Comment: Something is wrong in the question - all the strings you gave have the backslash at the *beginning*, not the *end* of the string. Is that on purpose? Also, how do you know the string is put there literally? Did you check the length? Sometimes text is printed escaped. Also, please show code.

Comment: What's the point of code? It's just a bunch of inserts in the data.sql file, as stated. Think `INSERT INTO TABLE(column) VALUES ('\1\')`? *All the strings I gave have the backslash at the beginning* is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think your understanding is correct. H2 doesn't support escaping with backslashes, at least not out of the box. How can this be reproduced? Your query executes just fine for me on H2 2.1.214

Comment: *What's the point of code?* Well, by posting just that, you've already answered the question I asked about whether you're properly using `PreparedStatement` parameters. And the answer is: no

Comment: @LukasEder thanks, that helped. I made a minimal example after some debugging, the cause of this issue was harder to find in my case because my init script is large. Since it has confidential info, I couldn't just go an share it in its entirety.

Comment: `ps.setString(1, "test;test");ps.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @g00se ok but like I said, I use Spring and just specify the `data.sql`, it's not me preparing the statements since it's done by Spring behind the scenes. Would be nice to know the cause...

Comment: Ah right. Driver bug?

Comment: @g00se guess so, I tested on the most recent version as well, same thing at my end.

Comment: backslash is the escape character. if you want a literal backslash in your database, you have to escape the backslash itself, e.g. `' ...something \\'`. If not escaped, it will escape the apostrophe and the string never ends (it ends eventually, the next time it encounters an apostrophe, i.e. the next opening apostrophe)

Comment: @knittl it's not an escape character in H2 strings apparently (as Lukas said). It escapes nowhere, but it interacts with that single quote in a weird way (check my minimal example). Using a double backslash just adds a double backslash to my database, I double-checked this whilst debugging.

Comment: I was wondering about that escape character myself but wasn't certain

Comment: @Bruno so doubling the backslash works, but inserts two backslashes into the database? Are you sure those are 2 _literal_ backslashes? It could be your IDE rendering two backslashes (an escape character + the backslash), so that you can copy the string. If you do `System.out.println(theStringFromTheDb)`, does it print two backslashes?

Comment: @knittl Yes I'm absolutely sure because I added '\1\3\\' and it printed out exactly this, and now that I fixed it by reordering my inserts (not my favourite kind of fix) it prints '\1\3\' so it prints every backslash. If you look at the minimal example, just reordering the inserts fixes it but it makes no sense. It's as if that backslash before the quote suddenly makes the parser think it needs to treat semicolons inside strings as delimiters.

Comment: @Bruno I still think that the backslash doesn't make the "semicolon inside the other string a terminator"; it simply escapes the single quote (perhaps not an H2 thing, but parsing the sql file?). This means that the "semicolon inside the string" is actually a "semicolon _outside_ of a string". `test` is a reserved word that could have special meaning – confusing the parser – have you tried with other words inside the second string, e.g. `foobar`? Also, since you linked the h2 docs, why not use unicode escapes to fix your immediate problem? `U&'\005C1\005C3\005C'` – would that work?

Comment: Unicode character string literals are only supported since H2 2.0.202, entirely outdated H2 1.4.200 doesn't have them. Anyway, `\\` is not an escape character in regular character string literals in H2 itself.

Comment: @knittl based on your *'perhaps not an H2 thing ...'*, I found it's caused by Spring's `ScriptUtils` class in its [`splitSQLScript`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/114d6a925639d9c1194c8a7562381001633a3820/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.java#L650) method. Not sure I get why they use a backslash as escape character there yet still add it as-is to the string builder. Anyways, unicode would be one fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by Spring's ScriptUtils class in its [splitSQLScript](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/114d6a925639d9c1194c8a7562381001633a3820/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.java#L650) method. It's a method that splits the `data.sql` script into queries with the semicolon as the default delimiter. Whilst scanning the script, it keeps track of whether or not it's within a statement surrounded by single or double quotes. When it encounters a backslash, it enters a sort of escape modus. The character after this backslash as well as the backslash itself are left as-is, but if the character after the backslash is a single or double quote it's effectively treated as if that quote were to be escaped.

One way to circumvent this is to use unicode :

```
U&'\1|005c' UESCAPE '|'
```

I wasn't able to make this work with just `U&'\1\005c'`.

The related Spring issue report can be found at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30098.

Comment: Can you create a bug report for the Spring project?

Comment: I added an issue to their repo, thanks for the reminder.